# erased md0, md1 and can't recreate them

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm

I previously had a working RAID 1 array. I think as a result of running `grub-install /dev/sdb` and `grub-install /dev/sdc` I somehow wiped my computer of `md0` and `md1`.

I need to set them up again. When I try to create the `md0` array, I am getting the following error.

```
/dev# mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 missing -f
mdadm: device /dev/sda1 not suitable for any style of array
```

It seems like Debian thinks the drive is already in an array but it's not.

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 250.0 GB, 250000000000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30394 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000080

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       30064   241489048+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2           30065       30394     2650725    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           30065       30394     2650693+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] 
unused devices: <none>

# mount
/dev/md0 on / type ext3 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620)
```

Comment: Is there any data on /dev/sda?

Comment: @ALex_hha Yes, all the data on my system is on `/dev/sda`

Comment: Did both `/dev/md0` or `/dev/md1` contain actual file systems, or was either used as backing store for LVM volume storage?

Comment: Could you show output of the "cat /proc/mdstat" ?

Comment: @ALex_hha See the bottom of the post. It is not even acknowledging `md0` and `md1` as it used to.

Comment: @MadHatter I do not believe either contained LVM. `md0` contained boot partitions, and `md1` contained other files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once things get this upset, I personally would mount each of the raw partitions as a read-only file system (eg, `mount -r /dev/sda1 /mnt`), dump the contents to tape / external drive / wherever you have space, recreate the arrays from scratch, and restore the data.

Comment: Would you say it is sufficient to simply `rsync` everything in `/`? (Sorry I'm new to this.)

Comment: rsync everything in `/` to where?

Comment: Also would "zeroing the superblock" be something of use? I feel like that because the System is listed as `Linux raid autodetect` I cannot readd them to the array. Also how do you propose I recreate the array from scratch such that `sda` isn't rejected?

Comment: rsync everything in `/` to a backup drive. I'm just wondering if that will "keep everything" so that I can simply restore it.

Comment: Hang on, is this array **the currently-mounted root**?  Can we get the output of `mount` in your question?

Comment: I think you're onto something! I added the output of `mount` to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Don't zero the superblock unless you intend to wipe the drive.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `/dev/md0` is mounted on `/`, I'd say it's quite alive and well.  If no such device file exists, take a look at `dmesg` to determine why.  Perhaps look at your udev configuration as well.

It isn't immediately clear what you are trying to accomplish by directing mdadm to instantiate a RAID1 array with only one device when that array is already created and mounted (likely it was created by the kernel's RAID autodetect).  It is no surprise at all that it won't allow you to do this.

If `/dev/md1` doesn't exist, you could probably create that using mdadm (assumedly out of `/dev/sda5` and something else).

You should avoid manipulating the root partition with mdadm at runtime.  If it isn't kernel autodetection that is creating it, it should be an initrd, and that is where mdadm should be doing its thing if required.

Comment: If `md0` is alive, why doesn't it show up in `/proc/mdstat`? My system refused to boot earlier because it couldn't find the root device in the usual `md0`, didn't exist or something. (so then I set GRUB to boot from `sda1`.)

I am just trying to get my RAID 1 set up back to the way it was. It was: `md1 : active raid1 sda5[0] sdb5[1]`; `md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]`. (sdb is unplugged for now).

Can you give me some advice on how to do this? Is it possible for me to plug in `sdb` and add it to md0? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: When I execute `mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda5 missing` I get
`mdadm: /dev/sda5 appears to be part of a raid array:
    level=raid1 devices=3 ctime=Wed Jun 16 00:01:41 2010`.

This means `md1` is out there as well, I just don't understand why it is not showing up in my `/proc/mdstat`.